# TF 2.0: how to convert 'tf.contrib.eager.num_gpus()'?

Tags: tensorflow

I found no way to get a 'num_gpus' function working in TF 2.0.
Thought it should be somehow possible with 'compat.v1'.

I used 'tensorflow.contrib.eager.num_gpus()' within a helper_function to initialize gpu if present.

What is the intended way to get the desired info in TF 2.0?

Comment: In my case this workaround would be enough:

if tf.test.gpu_device_name() != '/device:gpu:0':
  print('WARNING: GPU device not found.')
else:
  print('SUCCESS: Found GPU: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))

Comment: I don't have 2.0 installed right now, but it should be from tensorflow.python.eager import context, context.num_gpus

Comment: I tried tensorflow.python.eager import context, context.num_gpus() and it returns 0 while in tf1.13 i am getting 1

Comment: @WilliamD.Irons Thanks a lot. I can confirm, that your proposal is working with the current nightly build of TF2 preview.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the former tf.contrib.eager.num_gpus() use these SLOC:

```
from tensorflow.python.eager import context
blGPU = context.num_gpus()

if blGPU > 0 :
  with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
 ...
```